# How can i filter Many2one in Odoo v8

Tags: field, odoo-8

i have a Many2one field with 'ir.model' it gives me a list of different model used in my odoo, on changing the value of this field i want to filter my Many2one with 'ir.model.fields' to list the fields of the chosen model

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply put domain in field declaration of ir_model_field_id. e.g. 
domain = "[('ir_model_id','=',ir_model_id)]"

Answer (score 0):

suppose you want all fields name which used in selected model.
then in ir.model.fields object there is one reference of ir.model,

so simple:

take another many2one of ir.model.fields,
and give domain in this field like: 
[('model_id.id','=',your_selected_model_field_name.id)]